# PayuMoney Payment Gateway Not Working in Android Web View for Opencart

Tags: android, android-webview, opencart, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am using android web view for opencart website. Everything is working except payment gateway for payumoney. After clicking confirm order, the app is redirecting to gateway and once someone select other sub options, like netbanking, or wallet or debit card etc, its showing blank page.

The code is listed below:

```
enter protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); // replace settings with what matches your code


    //REMOTE RESOURCE
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    // LOCAL RESOURCE
    // mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Kindly tell what is missing.